# I'm getting function_clause for lists:nth/2 function

Tags: erlang

I'm having some problem with this code, it's really strange, maybe someone can tell me what is going on:

```
suggested_system_actor_data_for_hookup(RealActorId, RealActorName, RealActorLang, SuggestedUsers = [_|_]) ->
  case length(SuggestedUsers) > 0 of
    true ->
      SuggestedUserIndexRedisKey = "real_actor." ++ helper:convert_value_to_list(RealActorId) ++ "." ++
        helper:convert_value_to_list(RealActorLang) ++ ".hookup.suggested_user_index",
      NextIndex = next_index(SuggestedUserIndexRedisKey, SuggestedUsers),

      case NextIndex of
        not_found -> not_found;
        NextIndex ->
          case is_list(SuggestedUsers) of
            true ->
              Item = lists:nth(NextIndex, SuggestedUsers), % <--- throws error %
              SystemActorId = helper:convert_value_to_list(ej:get({"user_id"}, Item)),
              SystemActorSiteId = helper:convert_value_to_list(ej:get({"site_id"}, Item)),

              case helper:has_redis_key_last_visit_timestamp(RealActorId, SystemActorId) of
                {ok, no} ->
                  ?MODULE:send_visit_and_sleep(RealActorName, RealActorId, SystemActorId),
                  {SystemActorId, SystemActorSiteId};
                {ok, _LastVisitTimestamp} -> {SystemActorId, SystemActorSiteId}
              end;
            false ->
              helper:log_error("SuggestedUsers is not a list = " ++ helper:convert_value_to_list(SuggestedUsers), ?LINE, ?MODULE),
            not_found
          end
      end;
    false -> not_found
  end;
suggested_system_actor_data_for_hookup(_RealActorId, _RealActorName, _RealActorLang, _SuggestedUsers = []) ->
  not_found.
```

At line 194: Item = lists:nth(NextIndex, SuggestedUsers), is throwing an error in logs, I don't know why ?

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 4-Jul-2018::20:50:47 ===^M
Error in process <0.31747.0> on node 'animate_online_real_actors@online.anim.int' with exit value:^M
{function_clause,^M
    [{lists,nth,[1,[]],[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,170}]},^M
     {hookup,suggested_system_actor_data_for_hookup,4,^M
         [{file,^M
              "/projects/animate_online_real_actors/animate_online_real_actors/_build/prod/lib/animate_online_real_actors/src/hookup.erl"},^M
          {line,194}]},^M
     {hookup,send_hookup_with_verification_of_suggested_system_actor,12,^M
         [{file,^M
              "/projects/animate_online_real_actors/animate_online_real_actors/_build/prod/lib/animate_online_real_actors/src/hookup.erl"},^M
          {line,81}]},^M
     {hookup,process_hookup,3,^M
         [{file,^M
              "/projects/animate_online_real_actors/animate_online_real_actors/_build/prod/lib/animate_online_real_actors/src/hookup.erl"},^M
...etc
```

Comment: From the error message, it looks like you're trying to get the value at index 1 for an empty list, which fails because the list is empty.

Comment: In general, your code could be simplified quite a bit. You might consider posting it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and asking for help.

Comment: @Dogbert, I think that the implementation of lists:nth/2 is recursive, so the error message tells that the initial call to lists:nth/2 was done with an index equal to the list's length plus one (The code guaranties that the list is not empty).

Comment: @Pascal yes, you're right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is many useless code in your snippet. Since you use the pattern matching `SuggestedUsers = [_|_]` in the function head, you know that SuggestedUsers is a non empty list, so `length(SuggestedUsers) > 0` is always true, same for `is_list(SuggestedUsers)`.

Coming to the error, there are only 2 possible causes:

- NextIndex is not an integer > 0
- NextIndex is bigger than length(SuggestedUsers)

*The error report shows that NextIndex = length(SuggestedUsers) + 1*

I think you can simplify the function this way:

```
suggested_system_actor_data_for_hookup(RealActorId, RealActorName, RealActorLang, SuggestedUsers = [_|_]) ->
  SuggestedUserIndexRedisKey = "real_actor." ++ helper:convert_value_to_list(RealActorId) ++ "." ++
    helper:convert_value_to_list(RealActorLang) ++ ".hookup.suggested_user_index",
  NextIndex = next_index(SuggestedUserIndexRedisKey, SuggestedUsers),

  case (NextIndex > 0) and (NextIndex =< length(SuggestedUsers)) of
  % an atom is bigger than any integer, so the test covers the case NextIndex == not_found 
    false -> not_found;
    true ->
      Item = lists:nth(NextIndex, SuggestedUsers),
      SystemActorId = helper:convert_value_to_list(ej:get({"user_id"}, Item)),
      SystemActorSiteId = helper:convert_value_to_list(ej:get({"site_id"}, Item)),
      {ok,Answer} = helper:has_redis_key_last_visit_timestamp(RealActorId, SystemActorId),
      maybe_send_visit_and_sleep(Answer,RealActorName, RealActorId, SystemActorId);
      {SystemActorId, SystemActorSiteId}
    end;
suggested_system_actor_data_for_hookup(_RealActorId, _RealActorName, _RealActorLang, _SuggestedUsers = []) ->
  not_found.

maybe_send_visit_and_sleep(no,RealActorName, RealActorId, SystemActorId) ->
  send_visit_and_sleep(RealActorName, RealActorId, SystemActorId);
maybe_send_visit_and_sleep(_,_,_,_) ->
  ok.
```

Comment: Hi @Pascal, thanks for the reply, I will try the modification, and I know there are useless checking that I've left in the code, I just was focusing on solving the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Pascal, I modified the code and it seems that no the same errors had occurred. Also I used ?MODULE:send_visit_and_sleep(RealActorName, RealActorId, SystemActorId); because I'm using meck, otherwise it will not work